# How to set resolution higher on Flex desktop native (Air) app?

Tags: apache-flex, air, resolution

I'm trying to change the resolution for a flex native app (air) app running on a retina macbook. Flex apps in the browser render everything smoothly at 160dpi automatically but if I build the same app as Air install app, it renders at 72dpi and doesn't look as good. I know you can set a resolution in the application descriptor file for a mobile app but this isn't one. Also, I've tried setting the applicationDPI property on the WindowedApplication tag as well with no luck. Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: Instead of trying to set it; what happens if you run an app w/o it being set?  What is the value then?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com If I remember the Adobe docs correctly, they automatically choose 160dpi for *all* desktop apps. I believe they don't even run check what the DPI truly is before setting it.

Comment: @Apocalyptic0n3 Interesting for sure. If it's a Flex Framework thing; then Application may be able to be extended modified.  If it's a runtime thing; then you may have to wait for a runtime update...

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the responses - If I run it without it being set it says 160. If I actually set applicationDPI to 160 there is no change, 320 - it renders everything 1/2 the size but still blurry. I can understand they don't check what the DPI is before setting it but I find it odd that the web version renders differently (and really, really nice).

Answer (score 2):

For the record, to enable high resolution rendering in AIR desktop apps running on e.g. Retina Macbook Pros, set `<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>` in the `<initialWindow>` part of your app descriptor XML. Requires Adobe AIR 3.6 or newer.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-4cb7055d12d779150e8-8000

Answer (score 0):

http://gregsramblings.com/2010/05/06/scaling-an-adobe-air-application-to-fit-multiple-resolutions-and-netbooks/

<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml&quot; width="1019" height="680" scaleX="0.8" scaleY="0.8" applicationComplete="init()" ...>

<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml&quot; width="1019" height="680" preinitialize="initScreenSize()" applicationComplete="init()" ...>
...
...
            private function initScreenSize():void{
                var thisScreen:Screen = Screen.mainScreen;
                var newScaleX:Number = thisScreen.visibleBounds.width / 1019 * 0.98;
                var newScaleY:Number = thisScreen.visibleBounds.height / 680 * 0.98;
                var newScale:Number = Math.min(newScaleX,newScaleY,1);
                this.scaleX = newScale;
                this.scaleY = newScale;
                this.height = this.height * newScale;
                this.width = this.width * newScale;
            }

to scale the app based on the user’s resolution. Here’s the code: