# Adobe AIR/Flex on retina display on desktop (not iOS)

Tags: apache-flex, air

as you can see in the image my AIR application that is compiled with the AIR SDK 3.7(Flex4.5) looks pixelated on a Mac OSX with a retina display. I searched around and I can't find if it is possible to do anything to improve this.

You can compare the fonts on the menu and the one on the application.

Comment: Maybe try looking into this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html . It applies to Mobile projects, but there is a possibility that you could use it with your desktop projects too.

Comment: The problem could be that your flex sdk will only support densities up to 320 dpi and thus scales your content to fit the screen. The Apache Flex 3.10 SDK adds support for 440 dpi. (Sorry, just rechecked. MacBook has around 220 dpi, so this might not be very helpful)

Comment: If I remember correctly, AIR reports **all** desktop monitors as being a single DPI (72, I believe). AIR renders the app at that and then scales accordingly. I believe that is what is happening here.

Comment: @Pier no I did not found a fix, I do not work on this project anymore, the main issue is that I do not have a retina display to do testing and try different hacks and latest AIR versions.

Comment: put <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
within <initialWindow>
tag. from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592921/how-to-set-resolution-higher-on-flex-desktop-native-air-app

Answer (score 2):

To help people struggling...

You'll need to publish as an Application with runtime embedded.

Then right click your App and show package contents.

Open the plist file and add the following, before `</dict>`

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

Save it and open Terminal

Type touch and drag your app onto the terminal and hit enter.

Finally right click on your App and goto Get Info. Make sure "Open in Low Resolution is off.

Comment: I realize it has been a while since this question was asked, but I tried this solution for an Adobe Air app (with runtime embedded, Air 33 by Harman) on macOS Monetery 12.0.1, and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

in

```
 <initialWindow>
```

put

```
<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
```